# Derivative problem(I think, that is Implicit function theorem)

Tags: derivatives

I have a function: $$F(x,y) = 2x^4 + 3y^3 +5xy$$ And input $x$ and output $y$ we know that this relation
$F(x,y) = 10$ confirms. We know, that this happens when x = 1 and y = 1.

By small change of input $x$ (0.999) what will hapenn with $y$, so derivative $y'(x)$ of function $y(x)$ near x = 1 find.

How can we solve this problem?
Is is Implicit function theorem?Or just directional derivative? I have no idea of solution this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the implicit function theorem there exists $y(x)$ near $x=1$. Then

1. Taylor expansion of the first order gives
   $$
   y(0.999)\approx y(1)+y'(1)\cdot 0.001=1+0.001\cdot y'(1).
   $$
2. To find $y'(1)$ derivate $F(x,y(x))=10$ to get
   $$
   F_x'+F_y'\cdot y'(x)=0.
   $$

Answer (score 1):

Use a taylor series $$F(x+\Delta x, y+\Delta y)=F(x,y)+[\dfrac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x}] \cdot [\Delta x, \Delta y]^T+\mathcal{O}(\Delta^2 x,\Delta^2 y,\Delta x \Delta y) $$ and neglect higher order terms.

$$F(x+\Delta x, y+\Delta y)\approx F(x,y)+[\dfrac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x}] \cdot [\Delta x, \Delta y]^T $$

Now use your formula for $F(x,y)$ and solve for $\Delta y$:

$$2(x+\Delta x)^4+3(y+\Delta y)^3+5(x+\Delta x)(y+\Delta y) \approx 10+[8x^3+5y,9y^2+5x]_{x=1,y=1} \cdot [\Delta x, \Delta y]^T $$

$$2(0.999)^4+3(1+\Delta y)^3+5(0.999)(1+\Delta y) \approx 10+[13,14] \cdot [-0.001, \Delta y]^T $$

$$2(0.999)^4+3(1+\Delta y)^3+5(0.999)(1+\Delta y) \approx 10-0.013+14\Delta y$$

This is a cubic equation and you can solve it using Newton's method (numerically) or using Cardanos formula for the cubic equation (exact, , e.g. use wolfram alpha).

---

Alternatively you could neglect all terms in $\Delta y$ higher than $1$ to get
$$2(0.999)^4+3(1+3\Delta y)+5(0.999)(1+\Delta y) \approx 10-0.013+14\Delta y$$

Now this is a linear equation which is pretty easy to solve.